# Using one storyboard with multiples languages

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization, uistoryboard

I want to **localize** my app in multiple language (like 6 or 7) but i don't want to add as many as storyboard copy. So, for 6 differents languages, I want:

- One storyboard
- 6 Localizable.strings

In my storyboard, all components are outlets so i can localize them programmatically.

My issue is that i can't load application in language which don't have storyboard localization (but have localizable.strings), I get an error:

```
Could not find a storyboard named 'XXXX' in bundle NSBundle.
```

Is there a way to just use one storyboard with multiple Localizable files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your storyboard is still in the en.lproj folder. When your launches on a system that's configured to use another language, resources from that language's lproj will be used not the resources from the en.lproj. You need to mark your storyboard as not being localized in Xcode so that it doesn't get deployed to a en.lproj folder in your built app. Also make sure it's still included as a resource in the appropriate target of your project. You should be able to do all of this from the file inspector with your storyboard selected.

If you're targeting iOS 6.0 and later, you can use the Base.lproj feature. With that feature, your application just ships one storyboard, and multiple strings files and storyboard's strings are replaced at runtime with the strings from the appropriate language's strings file.

You can read more about base.lproj here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html

Comment: I used "Base Internationalization" in Project localizations infos and it worked. Thanks!